# Data table calculation error referencing a cell with text field

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am working on a model with several thousand rows of data, and several blank fields. I am having trouble with the following two calculations in a data table.

1. BMI = IFERROR(([@Weight]/[@Height]^2)*704,"")
2. Obese = IF([@BMI]>=30,1,0)

I must be doing something wrong, as the results of the second calculation are incorrect.

- For each cell where BMI = "", the Obese calculation is returning a "1", not a "0".

I am not sure why this is the case nor how to fix it.

Note: I also tried the following formula: `BMI = IFERROR(([@Weight]/[@Height]^2)*704,)`. All cells where there was an error as `0`. This works for calculating the Obese statement, but causes other problems as the "0" value messes up my average calculations.

Comment: Sample data together with the expected results would greatly improce this question. It might be inferred that hte errors you are experiencing are `#DIV/0!` due to zeros or blanks cells in `[@Height]` but without some sample data and what you expect to receive when a potential `#DIV/0!` is encountered, it is impossible to speculate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Excel *does* return `TRUE` when comparing a string to a number like this (*why* Excel does this a can't say)

The fix is to test for a number in the OBESE formula

```
 = IF(AND(ISNUMBER([@BMI]),[@BMI]>=30),1,0)
```